# Router's IP and devices external IP are different

Tags: ip, router

Is that normal if my router's IP address and external IP that my devices shows me are different? What does that mean?

[laptop screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfdpz.png)

[router screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na8U6.jpg)

Comment: Dude, just use a black box to completely blank out IPs if you want to censor them. `100.64.222.175` is entirely readable.

Comment: Since your ISP is using CGN, this is probably a residential network (off-topic here), and almost all residential ISP agreements forbid running servers from your residence, so the ISP simply doesn't care that this doesn't work for you. The RIRs have run out of IPv4 addresses to assign to ISPs, so the ISPs are conserving their precious pools of public IPv4 addresses for businesses willing to pay for the privilege.

Comment: @ceejayoz, that address is not a public IP address, so there is no problem sharing it. Multiple ISPs will assign that address to customers, in the same way that private IP addresses are used by multiple customers.

Comment: @RonMaupin Yeah, I know. I'm just saying if you're going to censor, don't do it like this. Next time it might be a SSN or something. :-p

Comment: @ceejayoz Interesting thing is: when I'am on my network I can connect to web server on the address, my router shows as external. In my ISP's tech support guy says I should be able to connect my server using dynamic IP and he don't know what the problem. Totally incompetent

Comment: @ceejayoz So. If my `traceroute` to google.com looks like this does that definetely means I am behind carrier-grade NAT? 
  
`1  100.64.128.1 (100.64.128.1)  19.628 ms  19.613 ms  19.723 ms  
 2  46.172.47.4 (46.172.47.4)  19.861 ms  20.484 ms  20.468 ms`

Comment: @RonMaupin could you please help me with the last comment?

Comment: I don't understand which comment you mean.

Comment: @RonMaupin If my traceroute to google.com looks like this does that definetely means I am behind carrier-grade NAT? 1 100.64.128.1 (100.64.128.1) 19.628 ms 19.613 ms 19.723 ms 2 46.172.47.4 (46.172.47.4) 19.861 ms 20.484 ms 20.468 ms

Comment: Yes. Any address in the `100.64.0.0/10` range is a Shared address. Shared addresses are used for CGN. See [RFC 6598, IANA-Reserved IPv4 Prefix for Shared Address Space](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6598). I have not heard of any ISPs using CGN for business networks. I think you have a residential network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your poor censoring of the IP address appears to have helped answer the question.

Doing a `whois 100.64.222.175` returns the following:

> This block is used as Shared Address Space. Traffic from these addresses does not come from IANA. IANA has simply reserved these numbers in its database and does not use or operate them. We are not the source of activity you may see on logs or in e-mail records. Please refer to http://www.iana.org/abuse/
>
> Shared Address Space can only be used in Service Provider networks or on routing equipment that is able to do address translation across router interfaces when addresses are identical on two different interfaces.

https://chrisgrundemann.com/index.php/2012/100640010/

> Shared transition space is meant to be used primarily in the middle layer of a service provider’s NAT444 deployment. In the illustration below, the green ‘IPv4 Internet’ uses globally unique “public” IPv4 addresses, the orange-ish ‘Customer Network’ on the bottom uses RFC1918 “private” IPv4 addresses, and the blue ‘ISP Network’ in the middle is where these new, shared transition (100.64.0.0/10), IPv4 addresses should be used. Global IPv6 addresses should be used throughout.

In short, you're on [a carrier-grade NAT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598) via your ISP that's between you and the public Internet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Could it be the reason I can't access web-server on my local machine from device in other network, despite all port forwarding and server settings are correct? I don't have a static IP, but even temporary IP that I have from `curl ipinfo.io/ip` is unavailable

Comment: @altjsus If you're behind a NAT it's highly unlikely you'll be able to run a webserver there. Pay for a static IP, use something like https://ngrok.com/, or get a real webhost or datacenter spot.

Answer (score -1):

Usually every router has two IP addresses:

- an external public IP address (some ISP use private IP also for external IP)
- an internal private IP address (eg: 192.168.1.x, 10.0.0.x)

[This link](http://whatismyipaddress.com/router) explains what is a router and how it works.

Comment: It has internal, and external ip and for some reason external one is not the same as my devices shows. Look at the screenshots I pinned, please.

Comment: Maybe you are using a transparent proxy